# Using multiple hyperlinks as submit and input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

Need the three "Options" to be hyperlinks that submit the "choice" form. When submitted, I would like the value to be the text of the option selected (i.e. value=Option1, Option2 orOption3) and all three to have the same name. (i.e. name = Options)

I saw [this](http://doctype.com/use-hyper-link-texts-instead-buttons-post-forms) and some other posts here, but did not work with my set up - many "hyperlink inputs" within the form.

I'm also using JQuery now, if it can be done using that library, I saw some posts on their forum about this but not sure about the answers....

Any help is appreciated.

```
<form action="cgi.exe" method=POST name="choice">  
     <tbody>                    
         <tr>                    
           <td>Option1</td>
           <td>Option2</td>
           <td>Option3</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just apply styles to your submit button to make it look like a link and avoid javascript altogether.

```
<input type="submit" style="background-color: #fff; border: 0; text-decoration: underline; color: #00c;" name="submit" value="Option1">
```

Otherwise, start here for help:

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You'd attach a click event to the item that then submits the form:

$('yourItem').click(function(){$('yourForm').submit()})

However, you don't really have a form there. Either you'd want those to be proper form INPUT elements or perhaps you need to use some sort of AJAX call instead.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want them to be proper form elements. Just a pure hyperlink (or at least displayed that way) No radio, text, or check, etc...

Comment: But if there is no form elements, then no data is being sent via the form submission.